# Detect which image in JLabel

Tags: java, user-interface, button

I have a `JLabel` and two `Jbutton`, named booking and next.When next button is clicked, another image will be displayed.

```
next.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (i >= 8) {
            i = 1;
        } else {
            i++;
        }
        i2 = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("image/" + i + ".jpg"));
        img.setIcon(i2);
    }
});
```

Assume image 2 is display in `JLabel` img. When click booking button, it will goes to the booking gui. How can I know which image is selected so it can go to the class respective ?

Comment: You can know it thanks to the value of `i`. If it is 2, then the icon in the label is 2.jpg.

Comment: It's easy just store your image number ("i " in your code) as a member of your class. I would rename this class member with a more descriptive name than "i "

Comment: Just instantiate your 'i' variable as a private member somewhere in your code and reference it later down the script after its been initialised by the listener method

Comment: @JBNizet when booking button is clicked, how can I know is 2.jpg?

Comment: `if (i == 2)` is all you need.

Comment: @JBNizet Let me try

Comment: @AI. can i recommend you use  a case statement for JB Nizet suggestion rather than nested if conditions?

Comment: @JBNizet I got the solution. Thanks

Comment: @MasterYoda Why ?

Comment: @AI. if you have a lot of images it is much tidier than using 8 conditional statements, however there are definitely better ways of doing this, for instance using iterations or recursion.

Comment: @MasterYoda Yes,I using switch case statement now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
    //private member used throughout the class
    private int i;
    i = 1;

    next.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                            if (i >= 8) {
                                i = 1;
                            } else {
                                i++;
                            }
                            i2 = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("image/" + i + ".jpg"));
                            img.setIcon(i2);
                        }
                    });
                }

    //call test() to get the value
    private void test()
    {
                    //Your 'i' variable will have been initialised by the listener method above
                    switch( i )
                    {
                       case 1:
                       //add your code here
                       break;
                       case 2:
                       break;
                       case 3:
                       break;
                       default:
                       break;
                    }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but you are not answering my question

Comment: I thought you just wanted to know how to retrieve the current image you were on? if that is the case the 'i' variable will tell you this and thats what is being returned in the above code.

Comment: The last method is completely useless. It returns what you give it as argument. Not to mention that the code doesn't compile.

Comment: @JBNizet its not supposed to compile, im not going to write an entire class to put a point across. The getIcon() method is there to be used later down the class and the println statement should be confined within a method. Sorry i should have been more specific

Comment: The only code you added to the OP's original code is `System.Out.Println("" + getIcon(i));`, which has two errors in it and a useless string concatenation, and the last method, which doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @JBNizet code has been updated. I hadnt tested this, was doing it in my head. Sorry...